# transitive relation in an adjacency matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, computation-theory, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to identify a transitive relationship between two elements .I am coding in c.

for eg: a->b is represented by a "1" in adjacency matrix in 1st row 2nd column.

so if a->b   and b-> c and c->d

i want to identify if a->d. no need to update the adjacency matrix.

approach i have adopted: check all the 1's in the row corresponding to a. lets say there is a 1 in second column ie for b. [(a->b)] , now check if b->d if not proceed to check all the 1's in B's row and continue till 26th row.

I am not really concerned with the complexity. i am just hoping to implement this.

Comment: Are you wanting to check whether the entire graph is transitive?  Or do you only care about 3 particular given elements in the graph?  When you say you "want to identify a->d", do you mean you want to see whether a->d exists in the graph?

Comment: i want transitive check for only the elements.. so if a->b b-> i am interested in knowing that a->c.

Comment: You wrote "b->" but I presume you meant "b->c", is that right? Also are you saying that if the graph contains some other element d, and a->b and b->d, you don't care whether a->d?

Comment: In other words: I see two possible questions that you might be asking, and I'm not sure which one it is.  Possibility #1: The input to the problem is a graph, and the output should be a boolean value indicating whether the graph is transitive.  Possibility #2: The input is a graph graph plus a list of 3 particular vertices in that graph (which we will call a, b and c), and the output should be a boolean value indicating whether those 3 vertices are transitive.  Which is it?  Or is it something else?

Comment: HI @j_random_hacker , My question is very simple. In an adjacency matrix if i have a 1 in row 0 column 1  it means A -> B. similarly if  b->c;  But i want to detect that a->c.

Comment: yes i meant b->c in previous comment. assuming case insensitivity.

Comment: Well in that case you can test it with a single `if` statement.

Comment: not that simple....  if a->b b->c c->d d->e...   i want to detect a->b,a->c,a->d.a->e ,b->c,b->d and so on...

Comment: So in other words, you mean "Possibility #1". I have now downvoted your question because you are unable to state it clearly, i.e. in terms of *what goes in* and *what you want to come out*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement a [*breadth-first search*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or a [*depth-first search*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Start at `a`, and stop when you reach `d`, or when you exhaust all options.

In your case, the depth-first search is somewhat easier to implement, because "plain" C lacks built-in dynamic queues needed for the breadth-first search.

If you do not care about the efficiency and you do not mind updating the matrix, implement the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm): it is formulated specifically for adjacency matrices, and takes only five lines to implement:

```
for (int k = 0 ; k != N ; k++)
    for (int i = 0 ; i != N ; i++)
        for (int j = 0 ; j != N ; j++)
            if (matrix[i][k] && matrix[k][j])
                matrix[i][j] = 1;
```

After running this algorithm, the resultant `matrix` contains the transitive closure of the original one.

Comment: TO implement a DFS i have to create a node and traverse . I was hoping to find some kind of a standard approach to do a transitivity check in adjacency matrix alone.

Comment: @KiranBangalore You absolutely, positively, do not need to create nodes. The beauty of the BFS and DFS is that they are abstract, to the point where the representation of your graph does not matter at all. Given a row, a DFS would go through each column in search of `1`, then go down recursively. Of course you could use Floyd-Warshall if performance does not matter to you.

Comment: Hi,  ya i see what you meant now. DFS appears to be the right way to go ahead. Else i can use Floyd-Warshall algorithm and calll it each time i need to check something.

Comment: @KiranBangalore You are right on the first part, but not the second: if you use Floyd Warshall, you need to call it only once, because it does the whole graph in one go. After running it once, you get the matrix for the transitive closure of the entire graph, so all you need to do after that is look up `matrix[i][j]`.

Comment: I think the OP wants to *test* for transitivity, so it would be better to replace the bottom line of your code with `if (!matrix[i][j]) return false; return true;`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That would break the algorithm, though: Floyd-Warshall is a dynamic programming algorithm, because `matrix[i][k] && matrix[k][j]` changes over time for the same values of `{i,j,k}` due to assignments in prior iterations.

Comment: True, but you don't need F-W here -- to test for transitivity, it's sufficient to examine every triple, and coincidentally that's what your F-W-like loop does! :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker That works only for one-away transitivity; for two-away transitivity, you would need a fourth loop; for three-away, a fifth one, and so on.

Comment: Nope, it works.  The condition for transitivity is that if a->b and b->c then a->c.  If you check that for all possible values of a, b and c, you've checked for transitivity.

Comment: (I'm guessing that when you say "two-away transitivity", you mean "If a->b and b->c and c->d, then we should check we also have a->d", but this test isn't necessary: if (a, b, c, d) fails to be "two-away transitive", then at least one of (a, b, c) and (a, c, d) must fail to be "one-away transitive".)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Returning `false` on `!matrix[i][j]` is incorrect, because that is what would happen when there is a path `a->b->c` but no path `a->c`. Essentially, doing so converts a calculator of transitive closures into a verifier of transitive closures.

Comment: I don't follow sorry -- verifying (in other words, testing) transitivity is what the OP wants! Unless you mean something else by "doing so".

Comment: @j_random_hacker If I modify the code to return false on `!matrix[i][j]`, the algorithm would not test transitivity; instead, it would test a particular property of the adjacency matrix - specifically, the algorithm would check if the matrix represents a complete transitive closure of some graph, i.e. "if there is *any* path from `A` to `D` (say, through `B` and `C`), there must also be a *direct* path from `A` to `D`".

Comment: That "particular property" you're talking about *is transitivity*! :) Suppose G is a graph. "G is transitive" `==` "G's adjacency matrix represents the complete transitive closure of some graph".

Comment: @j_random_hacker My impression after reading the question several times is that the OP would like to check a transitive relationship defined by a non-transitive matrix, i.e. one specifying only the direct relationships. Of course my understanding could be wrong.

Comment: A "transitive relationship" cannot exist in a "non-transitive matrix"! It might help to work through some examples (e.g. in my 4th comment) to convince yourself of this.  (I.e. try to construct a small example of a matrix that has a "transitive relationship" but is non-transitive.)

Comment: Hmmm... Actually if the OP is only interested in whether a transitive relationship exists for a *particular* 3 vertices, then no loops at all are needed: `return !a->b || (b->c ^ a->c);` I can't tell if that's what s/he means...  But I see no other way to interpret it.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I think the OP knows `a` and `d`, and he wants to know if there exists a direct or indirect path from `a` to `d`.

Comment: That could well be what s/he meant. I've asked the OP for clarification; hope I haven't wasted both our time! Also in the previous comment I should have said `return !((a->b) && (b->c) && !(a->c));`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707491/convert-recursive-perl-sub-to-iterative-routine.
I have a transitive closure question i am struggling with.